# canvas slide animation

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

Below is my code for a puzzle game that I found online [Puzzle game](http://www.sitepoint.com/image-manipulation-with-html5-canvas-a-sliding-puzzle-2/#fbid=iPtXjVMYhCA). I have modified the code slightly in order to get it to work with jQuery and everything is working fine.

I would like to be able to animate the tile that is clicked so it slides to the empty tile instead of being drawn there right away.

I'm fairly certain that its the draw function that I need to change but im not sure how. I was hoping that you guys could steer me in the right direction or provide me with some hints.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read my question.

```
var context = puzzle.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'images/images.jpg';
img.addEventListener('load', drawTiles, false);

var puzzle = $('#puzzle')[0];

var scale = $('#scale')[0];
var boardSize = puzzle.width;
var tileCount = scale.value;

var tileSize = boardSize / tileCount;

var clickLoc = new Object;
clickLoc.x = 0;
clickLoc.y = 0;

var emptyLoc = new Object;
emptyLoc.x = 0;
emptyLoc.y = 0;

var solved = false;

var boardParts = new Object;
setBoard();

scale.onchange = function() {
  tileCount = this.value;
  tileSize = boardSize / tileCount;
  setBoard();
  drawTiles();
};

puzzle.onmousemove = function(e) {
  clickLoc.x = Math.floor((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / tileSize);
  clickLoc.y = Math.floor((e.pageY - this.offsetTop) / tileSize);
};

puzzle.onclick = function() {
  if (distance(clickLoc.x, clickLoc.y, emptyLoc.x, emptyLoc.y) == 1) {
    slideTile(emptyLoc, clickLoc);
    drawTiles();
  }
  if (solved) {
    setTimeout(function() {alert("You solved it!");}, 500);
  }
};

function setBoard() {
  boardParts = new Array(tileCount);
  for (var i = 0; i < tileCount; ++i) {
    boardParts[i] = new Array(tileCount);
    for (var j = 0; j < tileCount; ++j) {
      boardParts[i][j] = new Object;
      boardParts[i][j].x = (tileCount - 1) - i;
      boardParts[i][j].y = (tileCount - 1) - j;
    }
  }
  emptyLoc.x = boardParts[tileCount - 1][tileCount - 1].x;
  emptyLoc.y = boardParts[tileCount - 1][tileCount - 1].y;
  solved = false;
}

function drawTiles() {
  context.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , boardSize , boardSize );
  for (var i = 0; i < tileCount; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < tileCount; ++j) {
      var x = boardParts[i][j].x;
      var y = boardParts[i][j].y;
      if(i != emptyLoc.x || j != emptyLoc.y || solved == true) {
        context.drawImage(img, x * tileSize, y * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize,
            i * tileSize, j * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);
      }
    }
  }
}

function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  return Math.abs(x1 - x2) + Math.abs(y1 - y2);
}

function slideTile(toLoc, fromLoc) {
  if (!solved) {
boardParts[toLoc.x][toLoc.y].x = boardParts[fromLoc.x][fromLoc.y].x;
boardParts[toLoc.x][toLoc.y].y = boardParts[fromLoc.x][fromLoc.y].y;
boardParts[fromLoc.x][fromLoc.y].x = tileCount -1;
boardParts[fromLoc.x][fromLoc.y].y = tileCount -1;
toLoc.x = fromLoc.x;
toLoc.y = fromLoc.y;
checkSolved();
    }
}

function checkSolved() {
  var flag = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < tileCount; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < tileCount; ++j) {
      if (boardParts[i][j].x != i || boardParts[i][j].y != j) {
        flag = false;
      }
    }
  }
  solved = flag;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to create an `update` function that is called by `setTimeout` or `setInterval` and has access to your `puzzle` object. This will allow you to control the number of frames drawn per second which will determine how fast your animation appears to be. This `update` method will want to call `drawTiles` and probably a modified `slideTile`.

Next, you will need to modify `slideTile` to slowly move the tile instead of quickly moving it. You will also probably want to have a flag to prevent users from clicking on another tile when one tile is sliding.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_animations) is a fairly good starting point for basic canvas animations.